# Android webview localstroge sometimes no data

Tags: android, webview

I'm working on an app for android, in webview loading local html file and this using localstroge. App working as normal. But just sometimes when open app html file loading but my localstroge data is empty. When I close the app and open again data is there. How can i solve this problem? I tried a alot of things for this. My code is:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class TasarrufMainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasarruf_main);


    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false); 
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    String databasePath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("databases", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
    webSettings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);


    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
}


@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    //creates a menu inflater
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    //generates a Menu from a menu resource file
    //R.menu.main_menu represents the ID of the XML resource file
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tasarruf_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{   
    //check selected menu item
    // R.id.exit is @+id/exit
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.exit){
        //close the Activity
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

}

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

}

and this is MyAppWebViewClient class;